# Text Field creates action not outlet

Tags: xcode, uitextfield

I'm working on my first app with multiple view screens and everything worked great on the first view, I added a couple text fields and was able to connect them to the controller as Outlets and obtain the value from them, manage it and spit it back out to a label.

I tried control-dragging the text fields on the second view to the secondControllerView and the only thing available when I do so is Action, no outlet, so its a function not a variable and I also cannot connect the labels to the code at all!

Anyone know why?

Comment: make sure you select your SecondViewController (name it starting with an uppercase letter) in your Main.storyboard at the interface builder and go to the inspector at the top right side and select the Custom class SecondViewController at the pull down menu

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 15):

Make sure in the identity inspector you selected the class for the `UIViewController` you are connecting your outlets to.

[image]

Comment: That worked for its intended purpose! The problem is that now I get a SIGABRT signal when I try to go to the next view, even if I comment out all the code I added

Comment: Because the links are already there even of you delete the code or comment it out. Remove the links by right click on the outlet on the story board and click "x" on the connections you made. Then make new connections again.